# Syntax issue within ODBC SQLExecDirect statement (C++)

Tags: c++, sql, odbc

[Snippet of the code that is giving me a syntax error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCjON.png)

```
    if(SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT,sqlConnH, &hStmt))
    cout << "failed to alloc stmt handle" << endl;
    if(SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(hStmt,(SQLWCHAR*)"SELECT TOP 10 [CaseId] 
    from YSeriesData" , SQL_NTS))
    {
    cout << "Fail on sql query" << endl;
    showError(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hStmt);
    }
    }
```

Have thus far checked many resources all of which seem to agree with the syntax I have implemented. Any suggestions for trouble shooting? Debugging has provided me with the following; [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server] Incorrect syntax near 0.

Comment: This bit `(SQLWCHAR*)"SELECT TOP 10 [....` you are trying to cast a narrow ANSI string to a wide string; this is never going to work.  Replace the cast with `L` ie `L"SELECT TOP 10 [...`  You calling a Unicode function application, so you need to pass wide Unicode strings.

Comment: This fix worked, thank you sir!